# Magento 2 Product not saving into the catalog_product_save_after event. "No such entity" error occured

Tags: magento2, customizable-options

I have added a programmatically customizable option into the product via observer **"catalog_product_save_after"** event but when I add **product->save()** then the

> no such entity error occurred.

Please check the below my code:

```
$option = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
     ->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
     ->setProductId($product->getId())
     ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
     ->addData($arrayOption);

$this->customoptionOperation($option, 'save');
$product->addOption($option);
$product->save(); // this gives the error no such entity
```

Comment: any solution please give me?